# Compiling CUDA with other C files

Tags: c, cuda, compilation

I'm relatively new to command line compiling (I normally use Xcode) and am having trouble getting the CUDA nvcc compiler to work with some existing C code.

My main.cu file contains

```
#include "eval.h"
#include "runge-kutta.h"
#include "plot.h"
```

I use the following build command:

```
nvcc -o cudaMain \"$file\" -Xlinker -framework,OpenGL,-framework,GLUT && ./cudaMain
```

where $file is the file location.

I get the following error on building:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
runge_kutta(diffeq_soln*, void (*)(float, float*, float*, unsigned long, void**), float*, float (*)(float, float*), unsigned long, void**)
```

It also lists other functions that are defined in eval.h.  My code runs fine when I compile using Xcode, and runge_kutta (and all other referenced functions) are defined in the included headers.  I ideally want to have my code compiled as a normal C project except for a single CUDA .cu file that would contain the device code.  How do I do this properly?  Nvcc doesn't seem to compile my main file unless it has a .cu extension.

Thanks

Comment: Please show us the relevant portion of your makefile and/or the compile commands you're using.

Comment: As I recall (from several years back, haven't used Cuda recently), nvcc expects C++, not C.  Have you accounted for the standard C++ name mangling?

Comment: @WilliamPursell what do you mean by that exactly? I tried changing the .c files to .cpp and that didn't work.

Comment: Rather than changing the file name to *.cpp, try adding `extern "C"` around the header file inclusion.

Comment: @WilliamPursell I changed the includes to extern "C" {
    #include "eval.h"
    #include "runge-kutta.h"
    #include "plot.h"
} and that still didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to compile and link your other source files. Something like:

```
nvcc -o cudaMain \"$file\" eval.cpp runge-kutta.cpp plot.cpp \
  -Xlinker -framework,OpenGL,-framework,GLUT
```

Comment: That was pretty obvious in hindsight! For anyone else having this issue however, the extern "C" was still required.